# sending mail from iphone app using skpsmtpmessage problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

i am trying to send mail using [skpsmtpmessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) . But the recipient  will see  id of SMTP authorization userid. The "fromEmail" variable is useless in this condition. How to send mail using another mail id .I can't change the sender name also.

Example

> testMsg.fromEmail = @"user1@gmail.com";
>
> testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
>
> testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
>
> testMsg.login = @"user2@gmail.com";
>
> testMsg.pass = @"mypassword";

recipient will see the sender name as "user2@gmail.com". But i want "user1@gmail.com" as the sender name. How i can send mail using "fromEmail"

Comment: It is easy to use [telnet to transfer mails](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipédia:Oracle#Envoyer_un_SMS_par_e-mail "Example of mail send with telnet TCP session"). It won't take long to you for developing your own implementation using libcurl for example. Also, I confirm Gmail don't check the existence of the address if it the same in the MAIL FROM:<> command and the header in the data command.

Answer (score 3):

In order to protect against spam, spoofing, etc. most serious mail services today requires you to send mail from the same email address as the one used for authentication. This is most likely also the case for Gmail.

If you are using Google as your mail provider, then you are probably not able to have your emails appears as being sent from a different mail account than the one you have authenticated as.